# Color Text vs. SpreadTab

Tags: spreadtab

Is it possible change the text color on spreadtab? All text is black and I would like change it to another color like yellow or red.
May anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome toTeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Welcome to SE. You didn't define what a spreadtab is, and you didn't show any LaTeX code, making it very difficult to help you. Please formulate a complete question.